# MvvmCross passing data from One viewmodel to another viewmodel

Tags: xamarin, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am working on Xamarin Android Application.I am using `MvvmCross` pattern for `ViewModels`.

Now,I want to pass data from one `ViewModel` to another viewmodel but don't want to navigate to that `ViewModel`. Instead of navigating to that `ViewModel` I want to navigate to another `ViewModel`.

e.g: I have three `ViewModels` V1,V2 and V3.Now I want to pass data from V1 to V2 but want to navigate to V3.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the MvvmCross Messenger to do this: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/Messenger

You need to subscribe for something on your viewmodel:

```
public class LocationViewModel 
: MvxViewModel
{
private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

public LocationViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger)
{
    _token = messenger.Subscribe<LocationMessage>(OnLocationMessage);
}

private void OnLocationMessage(LocationMessage locationMessage)
{
    Lat = locationMessage.Lat;
    Lng = locationMessage.Lng;
}

// remainder of ViewModel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the mentioned messenger plugin I would suggest to save the data you need to share in a "service", being the service a singleton class managed by MvvmCross:

```
CreatableTypes()
    .EndingWith("Service")
    .AsInterfaces()
    .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
```

In your view models you can use that singleton just by adding it to the constructor:

```
public WhateverViewModel(IService service)
```

The service will be singleton so your data will persists over the application live cycle.

So, in one of your view models you could do:

```
service.SharedData = new SharedData();
```

In another view model:

```
this.data = service.SharedData
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is using the [Messenger Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Messenger/) from MvvmCross.You can subscribe a certain kind of message in V2 and publish that message in V1 and then navigate to V3 in a seperate step.

```
// subscribing to a certain message type
this.logoutToken = this.messenger.Subscribe<LogoutMessage>(this.HandleLogoutMessage);

// Creating and sending a message
var logoutMessage = new LogoutMessage(this, "You have been logged out.");
this.messenger.Publish(logoutMessage);
```

**Note:** It is important to assign the `MessageToken` to a member variable (like in the other answer), because otherwise it will get cleaned up by the garbage collector.